# flask socketio message ordering with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flask, flask-socketio

In my flask socketio application, the messages in the chat are not sorted by date, they are ordered separately according to the user.

```
socket.on('message', function(data) {
      var sender = "{{ session['username'] }}";
    
      $('#chat').append(
        `<div class="message">
          <p class="message-date">${data.sent_at}</p>
          <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile_picture/default_profile_picture.jpg') }}" alt="Profile Picture" class="profile-picture" />
          <p>
            <em><span class="username">${data.username}:</span></em> ${data.msg}
          </p>
        </div>`
      );
    
      var chatDiv = document.getElementById("chat");
      chatDiv.scrollTop = chatDiv.scrollHeight;
    });
    

    $('#send').click(function(e) {
  var text = $('#text').val();
  if (text.trim() !== '') { 
    $('#text').val('');
    socket.emit('text', { msg: text });
  }
});

    $('#text').keypress(function(event) {
      if (event.which === 13 && !event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#send').click();
      }
    });

  });
```

In my flask socketio application, the messages in the chat are not sorted by date, they are ordered separately according to the user.

Comment: Do you have a problem with your server or your client? You have posted client code, but you claim the problem is on the server. Note that in the server, messages are received when the client sends them, there is nothing that sorts messages by the client that sends them.